# pre-installed apps and Unity Dash are gone

Tags: unity, 13.04, unity-dash, startup-applications

so i'm a newbie to Ubuntu..and i have a huge miss happening on my laptop right now 
pre-installed apps that came with ubuntu 13.04 were gone (i think something happened while updating them) tweaks and apps like terminal ubuntu software center are gone too so i tried to restart the PC thinking it will solve the problem but it gets worse when now i can't even find the unity dash or the bar on the top..i managed to make a new folder on the desktop and choose a random file and chose to run it with chromium that's and that's how i reached the website....now what do i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to delete the Software Centre Cache. Try to paste the command below on the terminal.

```
rm ~/.cache/software-center -R
```

Then you may want to reset unity to try to rebuild the cache.

```
unity --reset &
```

Comment: when i put the first command in xterm it says no such file or directory
and then when i put the second one it says "the program 'unity' is currently not installed you can install it by typing : sudo apt-get install unity
so i do type it and type my password but then it says "unmet dependencies try 'apt-get-f install' with no packages or specify a solution {1}+ exit 127     unity --reset

Comment: then i type the above command and it runs somethings and then says E:couldn't open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root ?
then i type the same command with a "sudo"
it runs some lines and then asks me if i'm sure that i want to continue type "Yes, do as i say!'
and when i type it...it says abort then nothing

Comment: Weird, how about change move the zeitgeist folder with `mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist  ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak` and then logout then login again?

Comment: actually i tried it again "the Yes, do as i say" command and it worked but it was removing things and when i restarted my PC to see the changes it booted me into the GNU Grub menu with 4 choices 1- ubuntu 
2-advanced options for ubuntu
3-windows recovery environment (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)
4-system set-up
the first choice always freezes on the reddish brown screen after the ubuntu logo
and the second choice has 4 versions of ubuntu with linux genrics two with recovery and two without it
and they all don't help 
now what can i do ?

Comment: You may be using the 3.8 kernel which usually is the culprit for bootup freezing issues. You may want to check on this : [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140753)

Comment: i can't find the 3.5 kernel all the ubuntu versions in the 2nd choice have the same 3.8.31 and 3.8.19 i think..

Comment: can you try to boot on the command line and issue the `sudo update-grub` command?

Comment: it says can't find command sudo

Comment: try update-grub

Comment: didn't work too